# No lags outside confidence bands. How to build ARIMA in this case?

Tags: arima, model-selection

While working with a data on *sp500* I have encountered one problem concerning the interpretation of *ac* and *pac* graphs. The problem is that none of them shows a significant lag outside of confidence band. I do not know how to choose *p* and *q* in this case in order to build my ARIMA model. Any help would be highly appreciated. I am also attaching the graphs.

[image: *ac d.lnclose*]

[image: *pac d.lnclose*]

Comment: If all ACF and PACF values are within the confidence bounds, then what about ARIMA(0,0,0)? (PACF value #2 seems to be borderline significant, though.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These functions inform us that there is no significant autoregressive component in your data, so `p = 0`.

You don't need to take differences of master data as well since you do not see declining autogression from lag 1 to 40 (referring to your charts), existence of which would be an indication of long memory, artifact of having not stationary (trendy data). So, `d = 0`.

Given that you cannot expect that your residuals contain any autoregressive dependency in the absence of any significant dependencies to model (and to produce residuals), the q component seems to be zero as well. So, `q = 0`.

```
ARIMA(0,0,0)
```

It looks like a good approximation of ARIMA parameters to your data.

**Update:** I just saw @Richard Hardy's comment while I was typing, so we came in simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Differencing of the variable was not my choice but rather a demand of a professor.

Comment: I understand you had already differenced raw SP500 prior to using ac/pac. So I mean you need no higher order differencing.

Comment: Differencing makes sense from a theoretical point of view. Stock prices should not tend towards an overall mean as an ARIMA(0,0,0) process. [To a first approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficient-market_hypothesis), the current price should include all currently known information, so only *increments* over today's price should be ARMA(0,0). That is, you should have a *random walk*, which is an ARIMA(0,1,0) process. The next step in modeling would be to model variance using an ARCH or GARCH process.